# Lambda expression to convert array/List of String to array/List of Integers

Tags: java, arrays, collections, lambda, java-8

Since Java 8 comes with powerful lambda expressions,

I would like to write a function to convert a List/array of Strings to array/List of Integers, Floats, Doubles etc..

In normal Java, it would be as simple as

```
for(String str : strList){
   intList.add(Integer.valueOf(str));
}
```

But how do I achieve the same with a lambda, given an array of Strings to be converted to an array of Integers.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You could create helper methods that would convert a list (array) of type `T` to a list (array) of type `U` using the [`map`](http://download.java.net/lambda/b78/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map%28java.util.function.Function%29) operation on [`stream`](http://download.java.net/lambda/b78/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

```
//for lists
public static <T, U> List<U> convertList(List<T> from, Function<T, U> func) {
    return from.stream().map(func).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

//for arrays
public static <T, U> U[] convertArray(T[] from, 
                                      Function<T, U> func, 
                                      IntFunction<U[]> generator) {
    return Arrays.stream(from).map(func).toArray(generator);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
//for lists
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("1","2","3");
List<Integer> integerList = convertList(stringList, s -> Integer.parseInt(s));

//for arrays
String[] stringArr = {"1","2","3"};
Double[] doubleArr = convertArray(stringArr, Double::parseDouble, Double[]::new);
```

---

Note that  `s -> Integer.parseInt(s)` could be replaced with `Integer::parseInt` (see [Method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html))

Comment: If you're using Guava, you can also use `Lists.transform()`.

Comment: Very good example. The function turns the code more versatile and powerful. Thks!!!

Answer (score 148):

```
List<Integer> intList = strList.stream()
                               .map(Integer::valueOf)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little?

Comment: This is converting a list of String into a stream then mapping/ converting every element of the list into Integer then collecting into a list.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since the point of lambdas (the original question asks for a lambda expression) is to avoid defining a new function. On top of which, this answer elegantly uses the existing Integer::valueOf function

Answer (score 38):

The helper methods from the accepted answer are not needed. [Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) can be used with lambdas or usually shortened using [Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). Streams enable functional operations. `map()` converts the elements and `collect(...)` or `toArray()` wrap the stream back up into an array or collection.

[Venkat Subramaniam's talk (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OpAgZvYXLQ) explains it better than me.

1 Convert `List<String>` to `List<Integer>`

```
List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<Integer> r1 = l1.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());

// the longer full lambda version:
List<Integer> r1 = l1.stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2 Convert `List<String>` to `int[]`

```
int[] r2 = l1.stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

3 Convert `String[]` to `List<Integer>`

```
String[] a1 = {"4", "5", "6"};
List<Integer> r3 = Stream.of(a1).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

4 Convert `String[]` to `int[]`

```
int[] r4 = Stream.of(a1).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

5 Convert `String[]` to `List<Double>`

```
List<Double> r5 = Stream.of(a1).map(Double::parseDouble).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

6 (bonus) Convert `int[]` to `String[]`

```
int[] a2 = {7, 8, 9};
String[] r6 = Arrays.stream(a2).mapToObj(Integer::toString).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Lots more variations are possible of course.

Also see [Ideone version of these examples](http://ideone.com/QhP98T). Can click fork and then run to run in the browser.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments, this is a much simpler version:
`Arrays.stream(stringArray).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()`
This way we can skip the whole conversion to and from a list.

---

I found another one line solution, but it's still pretty slow (takes about 100 times longer than a for cycle - tested on an array of 6000 0's)

```
String[] stringArray = ...
int[] out= Arrays.asList(stringArray).stream().map(Integer::parseInt).mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
```

What this does:

1. Arrays.asList() converts the array to a List
2. .stream converts it to a Stream (needed to perform a map)
3. .map(Integer::parseInt) converts all the elements in the stream to Integers
4. .mapToInt(i->i) converts all the Integers to ints (you don't have to do this if you only want Integers)
5. .toArray() converts the Stream back to an array

Comment: You don't need steps 1 and 4: `Arrays.stream(stringArray).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()`

Answer (score 7):

**For List :**

```
List<Integer> intList 
 = stringList.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**For Array :**

```
int[] intArray = Arrays.stream(stringArray).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use,

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");

    Integer[] array = list.stream()
        .map( v -> Integer.valueOf(v))
        .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find it in the previous answers, so, with Java 8 and streams:

Convert `String[]` to `Integer[]`:

```
Arrays.stream(stringArray).map(Integer::valueOf).toArray(Integer[]::new)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used maptoInt() with Lambda operation for converting string to Integer

```
int[] arr = Arrays.stream(stringArray).mapToInt(item -> Integer.parseInt(item)).toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition - control when string array doesn't have elements:

```
Arrays.stream(from).filter(t -> (t != null)&&!("".equals(t))).map(func).toArray(generator)
```

Answer (score -3):

Arrays.toString(int []) works for me.

Comment: I doesn't answer the question: "How to achieve this with lambdas".