# How to use Java Stream map for mapping between different types?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, functional-programming, java-stream

I have two arrays of equal size:

1. `int[] permutation`
2. `T[] source`

I want to do smth like this

```
Arrays.stream(permutation).map(i -> source[i]).toArray();
```

But it won't work saying: *Incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Arrays.stream` with an `int[]` will give you an `IntStream` so `map` will expect a `IntUnaryOperator` (a function `int -> int`).

The function you provide is of the type `int -> T` where T is an object (it would work if `T` was an `Integer` due to unboxing, but not for an unbounded generic type parameter, assuming it's a generic type).

What you are looking for is to use `mapToObj` instead, which expects an `IntFunction` (a function `int -> T`) and gives you back a `Stream<T>`:

```
//you might want to use the overloaded toArray() method also.
Arrays.stream(permutation).mapToObj(i -> source[i]).toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, I jumped into Stream<T>'s doc, but not IntStream.
Can you elaborate a bit more on toArray() part:
How to achieve something like this: stream.toArray(T[]::new)

Comment: @DmytriiShchadei, it's impossible due to erasure. I'd suggest to collect to the list instead (via `.collect(Collectors.toList())`) and return `List<T>`.

Comment: @DmytriiShchadei What Tagir Valeev said, or if you can provide an `IntFunction<T[]>` see how you can do it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057549/lambda-expression-to-convert-array-list-of-string-to-array-list-of-integers/23057743#23057743