# What is the best way to create a item list from items list in Java?

Tags: java, list

I want to create a specific item list from custom object list:

```
List<Long> getIdList(List<MyObject> items) {
     List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();
     for (MyObject obj : items) {
          result.add(obj.getId());
     }
     return result;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Java 8 has a way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057549/lambda-expression-to-convert-array-list-of-string-to-array-list-of-integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long[] getIdList(List<MyObject> items) {
    return items.stream().mapToLong(item -> item.getId()).toArray();
}
```

In ***Java8***, you can use `map` to yield.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is an issue try doing this,

```
long[] getIdList(List<MyObject> items) {
     long[] result = new long[items.size()];
     int i = 0;
     for (MyObject obj : items) {
          result[i] = obj.getId();
     }
     return result;
}

class MyObject
{
    long id;
    public void setId(long i)
    {
        id = i;
    }

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it's very nice way for performance! but I want shortest way :)