# Java 8, Convert file name array to file array

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I have an array of `String` file names and I want to convert them into `File` array. I am wandering whether there is a more elegant way of doing it rather than this one.

```
String[] names = {file1, file2, file3};
File[] files = new String[names.length];
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   files[i] = new File(names[i]);
}
```

**EDIT**
Thanks for noting in comments. I am using Java 8

Comment: Are you using java 8?

Comment: Java-8 similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057549/lambda-expression-to-convert-array-list-of-string-to-array-list-of-integers

Comment: Side note: Consider to use Path from the NIO.2 File API instead of File objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java 7 or less, using plain JDK, there's not. Since Java 8, you may use streams for this:

```
String[] names = {file1, file2, file3};
File[] files = Arrays.stream(names)
    .map(s -> new File(s))
    .toArray(size -> new File[names.length]);
```

Comment: `s -> new File(s)` can be simplified to `File::new`. Personally, I prefer method references.

Comment: @bcsb1001 careful when using that approach, specially for overloaded methods. After some reading and facing issues using `Class::method` when *method* is overloaded (even class constructors), I prefer to use the descriptive way.

Comment: You can also use `.toArray(File[]::new)`, but again: consider Path instead of File and possibly List instead of array.

Comment: @Puce I'm aware of that, but OP asked about using `File` and arrays. Just providing what he asked.