# Replacing int list with string list

Tags: java, android

What is the easiest way to replace

```
int[] engNumber = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
```

with

```
int[] bangNumber = new int[]{'১', '২', '৩', '৪', '৫', '৬', '৭', '৮', '৯', '০'};
```

in Android code ?

Comment: use `HashMap` collection

Comment: First, that's an array, not a list. Second, the second one is not a valid `int[]`, it is also not a `String[]` but a `char[]`. And third, how do you convert from one to the other?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein That won't compile.

Comment: invalid array int[] bangNumber = new int[]{'১', '২', '৩', '৪', '৫', '৬', '৭', '৮', '৯', '০'};,it should String[]

Comment: @FrankN.Stein After your edit, it does :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things:

1. Create a `Map` from the `eng` number to the `bang` number.

   ```
   public void test() {
       // Make a Map.
       int[] engNumber = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
       int[] bangNumber = new int[]{'১', '২', '৩', '৪', '৫', '৬', '৭', '৮', '৯', '০'};
       Map<Integer,Integer> toBang = new HashMap<>();
       for ( int i = 0; i < engNumber.length; i++) {
           toBang.put(engNumber[i], bangNumber[i]);
       }
       int bang3 = toBang.get(3);
   }
   ```
2. Rearrange the `bang` array so that the `0`th character represents `0` etc.

   ```
   public void test() {
       // Rearrange to make 0 at [0].
       int[] bangN = new int[]{'০', '১', '২', '৩', '৪', '৫', '৬', '৭', '৮', '৯'};
       int bang3 = bangN[3];
   }
   ```

Comment: Would this `int[] bangN = new int[]{'০', '১', '২', '৩', '৪', '৫', '৬', '৭', '৮', '৯'};` ever compile? I think I have to look for a different job, then... ;)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein To my surprise, it does. I guess it's because a char is just a 16-bit number in Java.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein - I always pre-compile my code before posting.

Comment: In VB NET a char is a string... :( and strings are made of characters.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein - Sorry to hear that - what a hideous kludge.

Answer (score 0):

[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057549/lambda-expression-to-convert-array-list-of-string-to-array-list-of-integers) may help

```
//for lists
public static <T, U> List<U> convertList(List<T> from, Function<T, U> func){
    return from.stream().map(func).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

//for arrays
public static <T, U> U[] convertArray(T[] from, Function<T, U> func, 
                                       IntFunction<U[]> generator){
    return Arrays.stream(from).map(func).toArray(generator);
}
```

use method

```
//for lists
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("1","2","3");
List<Integer> integerList = convertList(stringList, s -> Integer.parseInt(s));

//for arrays
String[] stringArr = {"1","2","3"};
Double[] doubleArr = convertArray(sArr, Double::parseDouble, Double[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String input; // the string with english numbers
String output; // the string with 'bang' numbers
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(); // we use this to build the output
int[] engNumber = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
char[] bangNumber = new char[]{'১', '২', '৩', '৪', '৫', '৬', '৭', '৮', '৯', '০'};

for(int i = 0, j = input.length(); i < j; i++)
    buffer.append((char)bangNumber[input.charAt(i) - 48)]);

output = buffer.toString();
```