# Convert list to map using lambda but for limited length

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to create a map using `groupingBy(...)` function in lambda. Now the problem I am facing is I am unable to convert list to map for particular condition

Code:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream
                       .range(0,120)
                       .mapToObj(Integer::new)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Expected functionality:

I need to collect a map whose key is key value like keys from 0 to 120 and values will increase like

```
[]
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
.
.
.
//so on upto 120


Map<Integer, List<Integer>> myMapOne = new HashMap<>();
        for (Integer inteter : list) {
            myMapOne.put(inteter, list.subList(0, list.indexOf(inteter)));
        }
```

What I am trying (idea):

```
Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = list
                              .stream()
                             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::new, list.subList(0, Integer::new)));
```

**Error**: not able to convert to List inside `groupingBy()` or not sure if I am missing something

How to solve this? Any help is welcome

Edit:

do I need to use method reference here?

Below is method

```
public static List<Integer> getList(Integer index, List<Integer> list) {
    return list.subList(0, list.indexOf(index));
}
```

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057549/lambda-expression-to-convert-array-list-of-string-to-array-list-of-integers

Comment: @SamOrozco thanks, but it returns `List` and I need `map`

Comment: The values of your Map are Integer from 0 to 120, but what should be the keys?

Comment: @Journeycorner , first thanks for reply,   the integer value that I'm getting from `List`, for reference I have added code under **Expected Functionality**

Comment: Btw. you should prefer static factory methods Integer:valueOf or boxed() (which also makes it clear it is just boxing and calls Integer::valueOf) to Integer::new .

Comment: @HelloWorld I still don't get it please give an example like: Map: 1 -> List from 1 to 10, 2 -> List from 11 to 20 ...

Comment: but then `collect(..)` gets complicated and  since I am new to lambda so still struggling to figure out what to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122557/discussion-between-journeycorner-and-helloworld).

Comment: Speaking as someone who loves streams/lambdas, I don't think this is a good use case for them.

Comment: @Rogue, actually I am trying to hit my head against `groupingBy(..),mapping(..) and entire lambda wall` so i m just trying to put things in my head :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
IntStream.range(0, 120)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        x -> x, 
        y -> IntStream.range(0, y).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Instead of `.mapToObj(Integer::new)`, you can use `boxed()`.
Then you can use `toMap()` to map the values to a key and a value. The key is just the identity, so you can use just `x->x`, the value is a new list, which can be created with `IntStream.range(0, y).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Dammit, exactly my answer, you was 2 minutes faster :D

Comment: @user140547 cant we involve  `groupingBy(..)` just asking

Comment: I am trying, but this code outputs 0=0, 120=120: Map<Integer, List<Integer>> foos = IntStream.of(0, 120)
                .boxed()
                .collect(groupingBy((x) -> x, mapping((y) -> y, toList())));

Comment: @Journeycorner `Stream.of(..)` will create stream of only value 0 &120

Comment: @user140547 I'm not sure, how can we use `groupingBy(..)` but thanks for teaching about the simplicity of `lambda`, and also thanks for this answer :)

Comment: Well the problem with `groupingBy(..)` is that it, well, groups its elements by some condition. So while it may be possible to solve it with `groupingBy()`, it is not a "natural" solution since you don't want to do any grouping. Just because it can be used to create a Map it does not mean it is a good fit for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your original approach of using `subList` was interesting, as it doesn’t waste space nor CPU time for copies of the same data. You can do the same with the `Stream` API:

```
List<Integer> all = IntStream.range(0, 120).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> myMapOne = IntStream.range(0, all.size()).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), i -> all.subList(0, i)));
```

Note that this doesn’t use `indexOf` as it’s not necessary, given the predictable contents of the `List`. You can elide it in your loop variant as well.

---

But, of course, you actually don’t need real storage for this `List` at all, so, if you are willing to write a bit more code, you can use:

```
final class NaturalNumbers extends AbstractList<Integer> implements RandomAccess {
    final int limit;
    NaturalNumbers(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
    public int size() { return limit; }
    public Integer get(int index) { return index; }
    // the next two are not required, but nice to have
    @Override public void forEach(Consumer<? super Integer> action) {
        spliterator().forEachRemaining(action);
    }
    @Override public Spliterator<Integer> spliterator() {
        return IntStream.range(0, limit).spliterator();
    }
}
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> myMapOne = IntStream.range(0, 120).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), NaturalNumbers::new));
```

---

Just for completeness, using `groupingBy` here, would be possible when using the `flatMapping` collector shown at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39131049/2711488):

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> myMapOne = IntStream.range(0, 120).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
        flatMapping(i -> IntStream.range(0, i).boxed(), Collectors.toList())));
```

But for this task, it’s no win compared to the other solutions.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me this (especially `function.Identity` that   can be very handy :)