# Lambda Java 8 - How to convert while streaming a String List to a Date List

Tags: java, lambda

Is there a way to also convert (while streaming and collecting) a List of Strings to a new List of Dates?

**My attempt:**

I defined a SimpleDateFormat and tried to use that in the follwing code, but I can't get it working all together.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");

ArrayList<Date> dateList = stringList.stream()
              .filter(s -> s.startsWith("<"))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Solution**

Based on the hints to use map, I got a working solution for now that looks like this. Of course any optimization on this is welcomed!

```
int year = 2016;
int month = 2;
int day = 15;


final List<LocalDate> dateListEarlier = dateList.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.startsWith("<"))
        .map(s -> s.substring(1).trim())
        .map(s -> LocalDate.parse(s, formatter))
        .sorted()
        .filter(d -> d.isAfter(LocalDate.of(year, month, day)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to actually convert your String using this defined `simpleDateFormat`. You filter some stuff and that's all. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057549/lambda-expression-to-convert-array-list-of-string-to-array-list-of-integers) are several examples about type conversion in streams.

Comment: `map` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are using `Java8`, you could utilize the new `DateTime` API

```
    List<String> dateStrings = Arrays.asList("12.10.2016", "13.10.2016", "14.10.2016");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    List<LocalDate> localDates = dateStrings.stream().map(date -> LocalDate.parse(date, formatter)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(localDates);
```

Ouptut

```
[2016-10-12, 2016-10-13, 2016-10-14]
```

Comment: why does this not work for   the below list?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `map` method.

```
final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");

final List<Date> dateList = strings.stream()
                                   .filter(s -> s.startsWith("<"))
                                   .map(s -> { 
                                          try {
                                             simpleDateFormat.parse(s));
                                          } catch (final ParseException e) {
                                             throw new RuntimeException("Parse failed", e);
                                          }
                                    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: *Error 1:* cannot convert from List<Date> to ArrayList<Date>. *Error 2:* Unhandled exception type ParseException

Comment: Still won't compile.

Comment: `toList` returns `List` of objects not `ArrayList`

Comment: That's what I get for copying OP ;)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to write a function that maps `String` to `Date` object, see below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringList.add("10.10.2014");

    Function<String, Date> function = new Function<String, Date>() {

        @Override
        public Date apply(String s) {
            try {
                return simpleDateFormat.parse(s);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    };

    List<Date> collect = stringList.stream().map(function).collect(Collectors.<Date>toList());

    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

Comment: `return null` when encountering bad data is likely a bad idea.

Comment: Since you're using Java 8 features, is there any reason you're creating an anonymous class, rather than a lambda expression block?

Comment: Corrected null. Also, there is no specific reason. I preferred an anonymous class just for the readability.