# Creating an ArrayList from a method which returns a String

Tags: java

I have an custom class `InfoAQ` which has a method called `public String getSeqInf()`. Now I have an `ArrayList<InfoAQ> infList` and
I **need** an `ArrayList<String>strList = new ArrayList<String>`with the content from `getSeqInf()`for each element.

This is the way Im doing it right now ...

```
for(InfoAQ currentInf : infList)
  strList.add(currentInf.getSeqInf());
```

Is there an alternative way to make it ? Maybe a faster one or one liner ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lambda expression to convert array/List of String to array/List of Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057549/lambda-expression-to-convert-array-list-of-string-to-array-list-of-integers)

Comment: Try this --> List<String> outputList = list.stream().map(it -> it.getSeqInf()).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: What you wrote can be one line. Just delete the new line you added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
strList = infList.stream().map(e -> g.getSeqInf()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `map` step can be also written in another way:

```
strList = infList.stream().map(InfoAQ::getSeqInf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which is know as method reference passing. Those two solutions are equivalent.

Comment: InfoAQ::getSeqInf ?

Comment: It is an equivalent way for map. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Using streams

```
infList.stream()
   .map(InfoAQ::getSeqInf)
   .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
```

Using `Collectors.toCollection` here to create an `ArrayList` that will hold the results as you do in your case. (Important if you *do* care about the result list type as `Collectors.toList()` does not guarantee this)

May not be the fastest as using stream has some overhead. You need to measure/benchmark to find out its performance

Answer (score 0):

Also maybe this one:

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
infList.forEach(e -> strList.add(e.getSeqInf()));
```

Answer (score 0):

And there is another one (-liner, if you format it in a single line):

```
infList.forEach(currentInf -> {strList.add(currentInf.getSeqInf());});
```

while I would prefer a formatting in more lines:

```
infList.forEach(currentInf -> {
    strList.add(currentInf.getSeqInf());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This code will iterate all the data in the list, as getSeqInf returns a String, the collect method will store all returns of the getSeqInf method in a list.


`List listString = infList.stream().map(InfoAQ::getSeqInf).collect(Collectors.toList());`

or 

`
ArrayList<String> listString = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < infoAq.size(); i++) {
     listString.add(infoAq.get(i).getSeqInf());
}`
```