# Why do I get an error in a simple cast of String to Integer in an List<String>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to cast a `List<String>` to an Array `Integer[]`. I made this function:

```
public static Integer[] castToArrayInteger(List<String> cadenas) {
    Integer[] enteros = new Integer[cadenas.size()];
    for(int iteracion = 0; iteracion < cadenas.size(); iteracion++) {
        enteros[iteracion] = Integer.valueOf(cadenas.get(iteracion));
    }
    return enteros;
}
```

Then I made a Test:

```
@Test
public void castToArrayInteger() {
    List<String> cadenas = new ArrayList<>();
    Integer[] enteros = new Integer[3];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 3) {
        cadenas.add(String.valueOf(i));
        enteros[i] = i;
        i++;
    }
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(enteros, ArregloUtils.castToArrayInteger(cadenas)) ;
}
```

It works like a charm. But when I use the  function in an web application, it fails.

The debug tool mark the line :

```
Integer.valueOf(cadenas.get(iteracion));
```

The error is

```
Integer is not compatible with the declared Type String.
```

This is the line where I Implemented the function, getRubros:

```
List<CatalogoDto> rubros =  this.catalogoService.buscar(
                ArregloUtils.castToArrayInteger(this.getProductor().getRubrosId()));
```

The method `getRubrosId()` get the data in a `List<String>`

I would like to know why do I have this issue.

Environment:
Java 1.8
Wildfly 16
Red Hat CodeReadyStudio.

I expected for this input:

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
data.add("1");
data.add("2");
data.add("3");

Integer output = [1,2,3];
```

Comment: Point of terminology: You are not _casting_.

Comment: `enteros[iteracion] = Integer.valueOf(cadenas.get(iteracion));`

Comment: Yes, that's _parsing_ a string and _converting_ it into an integer, but it's not _casting_.

Comment: Don't think the casting is needed.

Comment: me neither, but the app throw that error.

Comment: This is not a cast. This is parsing the individual elements. "Cast" has a very specific meaning: it means instructing the system to use the value as another type *without* converting it to a different object in memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lambda expression to convert array/List of String to array/List of Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057549/lambda-expression-to-convert-array-list-of-string-to-array-list-of-integers)

Comment: 1) There _must_ be something important you're omitting in your question, since a simple test program, even outside a `@Test` framework, works fine. — 2) is there any reason you can't just use [yourList.toArray(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-)?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear the part where you convert **valid** `String` to `int` entries using `Integer.valueOf` (as in your test for example) is not the actual problem. You are trying to convert `String` entries that **cannot** be converted to strings as your error message indicated:

> Integer is not compatible with the declared Type String.

You can confirm that the problem is not in the conversion process itself but *what* you're trying to convert by running this code below:

```
    List<String> sData = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    sData.add("1"); sData.add("2"); sData.add("3");

    Integer[] iData = new Integer[sData.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < sData.size(); i++) {
        iData[i] = Integer.valueOf(sData.get(i));
        System.out.println(iData[i]);
    }
```

I would recommend inspecting the entries you are converting at runtime using some debugging technique like breakpoints or simple logging. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
In fact, the method `this.getRubrosId()`  is declared as List<String> but in runtime the method returns Integer, I was debugging the application and I saw that weird behavior. 
Then my question is: Why the JVM returns a List of Integer, when I declared in a way specific that I want a List<String>.

Comment: No, I am getting crazy. I've never seen this kind of behavior.