# Error trying to convert a List<String> to List<Integer>

Tags: java, list, methods, integer, java-stream

I am currently trying to convert a `List<String>` to `List<Integer>` with streams and so. But I don't know what is happening; when it runs it gives me some errors that are driving me mad.

I have already tried everything I (poorly) know from Streams in Java, also tried to do without them, but the thing is that I want to make it in a functional way.
I give to my method (leeFichero) a string f, which is just the path of my txt file. And all I want the method to do is return a `List<Integer>` with the values in it.
The contents of the file is this:

> ```
> -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3
> 1,3,5,7,9
> 100
> 2,4,6,8,10
> ```

```
 public static List<Integer> leeFichero(String f) {
    List<String>lineas=null;
    try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        lineas = bf.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
        bf.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    List<Integer> intList = lineas.stream().map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return intList;
}
```

And when I run it, it gives me this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at ejercicios.ejercicio1.lambda$0(ejercicio1.java:108)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at ejercicios.ejercicio1.leeFichero(ejercicio1.java:108)
at ejercicios.ejercicio1.main(ejercicio1.java:48)
```

Comment: You need to split the line with `,`

Comment: Start by reading the error message. it tells you what you're doing wrong. You're trying to parse the string `"-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3"` as an Integer. The logical conclusion is that your way of parsing your file is wrong, since instead of returning one String per integer in the file, it returns a STring containing all the integers. And indeed. Your parsing reads the file line by line, but the file contains a single line with many integers separated by a comma.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lambda expression to convert array/List of String to array/List of Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057549/lambda-expression-to-convert-array-list-of-string-to-array-list-of-integers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `split` the lines of `String` using the delimeter `,` and `flatMap` them to collect as a List.

```
lineas = bf.lines()
        .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(",")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then return the `List<Integer>` mapped as:

```
return lineas.stream()
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: On a different note, initialize the array list as empty instead of `null` such as `List<String> lineas = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't see the purpose of the many temporary variables in your method. Second, I would prefer a compiled `Pattern` for use in splitting the lines (here the `\\s*` are used to consume any whitespace that might be between digits and commas). Prefer [`try-with-Resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to manual resource management. Then, as already noted, use a `flapMap()` and then `map()` - but I would simply return the result(s) directly. Something like,

```
public static List<Integer> leeFichero(String f) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*");
    try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
        return bf.lines().flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(p.split(s)))
                .map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```