# How to convert string of values into array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string, ie `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17`. How do I get each value and convert it into an array? `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]`. I can't find any suggestions about this method. Can help? I did try using regex, but it just simply remove ',' and make the string into one long sentence with indistinguishable value. Is it ideal to get value before and after ',' with regex and put it into `[]`?

Comment: What about `String.split()`?

Comment: Do you want an array *of ints* ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use following solution

```
String dummy = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17";
String[] dummyArr = dummy.split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to convert string to an array of Integer.

```
String baseString = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17";
String[] baseArray = baseString.split(",");

int[] myArray = new int[baseArray.length];
for(int i = 0; i < baseArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(baseArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: You could also use Streams for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057549/lambda-expression-to-convert-array-list-of-string-to-array-list-of-integers which will be more elegant

Answer (score 1):

Java provides method [Split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) with regex argument to manipulate strings.

Follow this example:

```
String strNumbers= "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17";
String[] strNumbersArr= strNumbers.split(",");
```

You can convert an array of string in array of integer with Streams

```
int[] numbersArr =  Arrays.stream(strNumbersArr).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.split() and you will get your desired array.

```
String s1="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17";  
String[] mumbers=s1.split(",");    //splits the string based on comma

for(String ss:numbers){  
    System.out.println(ss);  
}
```

Comment: using simplified `for` really great idea here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the working Example

```
String csv = "Apple, Google, Samsung";

String[] elements = csv.split(",");
List<String> fixedLenghtList = Arrays.asList(elements);
ArrayList<String> listOfString = new ArrayList<String>(fixedLenghtList);


//ouput
[Apple, Google, Samsung]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want an int array

```
        String s = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17";
        String[] split = s.split(",");
        int[] result = Arrays.stream(split).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```